# Using Grunt Compass task to produce production CSS code without debug info

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman RC1.1 to generate my project and have [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) loaded to use Scss in my project.

When I perform `grunt build`, the resulting CSS is minified but full of debug comments. It looks like this:

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/\/Users\/myname\/Sites\/project\/app\/components\/sass-bootstrap\/lib\/_reset\.scss}line{font-family...
```

Where the whole thing is polluted with a lot of `-sass-debug-info` code.

In Gruntfile.js, I have set the following option (among a bunch of other options) to turn debug comments off for the /dist/ css file:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I incorrect in assuming turning off the `debugInfo` by setting it to `false` should fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this error most recently, the issue is that compass/grunt won't recompile your css file unless there is a change in one of the files being watched. Not only do you need to update the debugInfo:false but you will need to make a change to your scss file to have it recompile your css file without the debug information inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the output syle compressed https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#debuginfo and environment: production

Comment: I changed `debugInfo` to both `outputStyle` and `environment` and the results were the same :(

Comment: Do you have a config.rb that may be conflicting with the settings?

Comment: I figured it out. This was a preventable error on my part. For some reason, within the /styles/ directory, I had a .css file that contained all this debug comments. So grunt grabbed everything in that directory and compressed it together.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the value of debugInfo to false from true at compass.server.options.debugInfo

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
    }
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      //set degbugInfo false to produce css code without sass debugInfo
      debugInfo: false
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Grunt compass uses a cache located at ".tmp". You should clean this folder when you run Grunt build task, or do it manually.

Comment: Why downvote without any explanation? This technic works for me, just wanted to share it.